# Copy certain table row from one table to another

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, row

I have a word document with several tables.
The first table in the document is supposed to be a summary table containing copies of certain rows of the other tables in the document.

How would I have to tackle the automated population of the summary table with the specific rows of the other tables?

I assume there is no built in function and I'd have to use VBA.
I'd think I have to mark the rows to be copied with some marker (e.g.: "###") for the code to detect. Then the code would have to go through the document, find all the "###", mark them as "dealt with" (e.g., with "##-") and copy/append the respective row into the first table, and then loop through the document again.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark the row(s) using bookmarks; name them with a special prefix. Loop through the bookmarks collection, check the prefix and if it's the correct one, append the row to the sumamry table. You can delete the bookmark in the process, if you wish.

Here's some sample code which works for me in a quick test. The boomkark prefix is "tbl"; if you don't want it to be visible to the user, start the name with an underscore (_).

The target range for the summary table is at the start of the document. Change the assignment to the rng object if you need it elsewhere.

```
Dim doc As word.Document
Dim rng As word.Range
Dim rwSource As word.Row
Dim bkm As word.Bookmark

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rng = doc.Range(0, 0)

For Each bkm In doc.Bookmarks
    If Left(bkm.Name, 3) = "Tbl" Then
        rng.FormattedText = bkm.Range.FormattedText
        rng.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    End If
Next
```

Note: I tried using REF fields to pick up the bookmarked rows, without needing VBA. This inserted an empty row between each REF field, however, so I don't think it can be done without VBA.

Comment: Thanks, Cindy! I'll try it out soonest